# firebase_auth/null-error : Host platform returned null value for non-null return value on iOS only

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

In my flutter application, there's a form where the user can register to the app, and I added a function that checks if the user already exists in firebase :

```
Future<bool> checkIfEmailInUse() async {
    try {
      final list = await FirebaseAuth.instance
          .fetchSignInMethodsForEmail(_emailController.text);
      if (list.isNotEmpty) {
        print('USER EXISTS');
        return true;
      } else {
        print('USER DOESNT EXISTS');
        return false;
      }
    } catch (error) {
      print('ERROR');
      print(error);
      return false;
    }
  }
```

And I call it in the button that will submit the form :

```
                       RoundedTextButton(
                            text: 'Next',
                            onPressed: () async {
                              try {
                                  final emailInUse = await checkIfEmailInUse();

                                  if (!emailInUse) {

                                   // User is pushed to next screen

                                  } else {
                                   
                                    showSnackBar(context,
                                        'This email already exists');
                                  }
                              } catch (e) {
                                print(e);
                              }
                            }),
```

The idea is that the button will check the if the `_emailController.text` (the email typed in the textfield) == an email already registered in firebase, the user won't be pushed to the next screen.

Here's where I don't get it :

The controller works well, if I `print(_emailController.text)` it returns the actual email that is typed in the text field.

If `_emailController.text == 'emailAlreadyInFirebase'`, it prints `USER EXISTS` and the user is pushed to the next screen.

But if `_emailController.text == 'emailNotInFirebase'`, instead of printing `USER DOESNT EXISTS`, it prints `[firebase_auth/null-error] Host platform returned null value for non-null return value`.

The application works fine with firebase and firestore, I had no issues regarding firebase auth, only this issue since I added this checker function.

**This error appears on iOS only** and not on Android.
I've always used the application on the iOS emulator with firebase without any issue. Firebase is well configured for both iOS and Android.

Where is the problem ?

Comment: Please try with another simulator.

Comment: I did, still the same error. I also erased the emulator's cache as well but it doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: then check your iOS app setting on firebase

Comment: did you find a solution? Everything was fine here in 10.10.0, but I needed to update and this error appears only in iOS